# How do I make tableview cells completely opaque, when overlaying them on top of a background?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a search bar that displays results in a tableview.  The search bar is always visible.  However, I hide the tableview by default, until the user starts typing within the search bar.  Therefore, the tableview cells are only visible when the search bar is actively used.

The reason I do this is that I'm displaying various labels and text in the background.

I've tried hiding and unhiding the labels and text in the background when the search bar is activated, and subsequently de-activated.  This works.  However, is there a more elegant way?

```
// TableView is hidden by default in viewDidLoad()

SearchBarTableView.isHidden = true

// TableView is  also hidden when searchBarCancelButtonClicked

SearchBarTableView.isHidden = true

// TableView is turned on within the searchBar function

SearchBarTableView.isHidden = false
```

The problem with the existing code is that the tableviewcells have a transparent background, where the searchbar results overlay on top of my other labels and text in the background.

I'd like the tableviewcells to have a solid background, that erases everything under it.

Comment: What if you create custom cells for SearchTableViewController and make background not transparent&

Comment: I am using custom cells for SearchTableViewController.   Good point... let me try.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding your idea.  I tried setting the tableviewcell to a coloured background, alpha = 1.0, and the Opaque checkbox is ticked on.  The background colour does change for the cells, but the label text under the tableviewcells are still visible.

Comment: Add new UIView to your cell as a container of all elements. Add all elements inside it. Make it is (container view) background whatever color you want. It must work

Comment: Thanks!  Will try this.  I've just hidden/unhidden the labels and text temporarily as needed.  I think your way will also work!